# An internal error occurred during: "Server metrics periodic save" when starting Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse

Since a week or two I receive this error message when my Eclipse is starting.
I've searched for this error, but I seem to be the first one with this exact error.

This is the message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Server metrics periodic save".
>   com/genuitec/eclipse/core/util/GenuitecProduct

[image: The error message]

Any ideas how to solve this?

I'm using Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen. And this is a list of the Genuitic plugins that are installed:
[image: List of installed Genuitec plugins]

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is still under development and won't be finally released until June 2017. It may be that the extra plugins you are using haven't been fully tested with it yet.

Comment: @greg-449 Agreed! But since I've no idea what exactly is causing this, I was hoping someone can tell me more about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wish that helps you;

I've encountered same error message popping up periodically until I figure out that:

> Eclipse Oxygen + **Darkest Dark theme + JDK 9** =
>   ExceptionInInitializerError

```
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Server metrics periodic save".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.jniwrapper.util.ProcessorInfo.b(SourceFile:95)
    at com.jniwrapper.util.ProcessorInfo.getInstance(SourceFile:88)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.core.activation.SystemIdFactory.D(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.core.activation.SystemIdFactory.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.core.LicenseUtil.getSystemId(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.monitor.internal.collector.server.ServerMetricsCollector.getSystemId(ServerMetricsCollector.java:526)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.monitor.internal.collector.server.ServerMetricsCollector.saveToFile(ServerMetricsCollector.java:364)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.monitor.internal.collector.server.ServerMetricsCollector.access$5(ServerMetricsCollector.java:304)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.monitor.internal.collector.server.ServerMetricsCollector$PeriodicSaveJob.run(ServerMetricsCollector.java:863)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: com.jniwrapper.LibraryNotFoundException: Cannot find JNIWrapper native library (libjniwrap.jnilib) in java.library.path: /Users/aghoneim/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
```

---

I was able to resolve this issue by reconfiguring Eclipse to use **older jdk** by changing the -vm option under **eclipse.ini** to use jdk1.8.0_152

In my case (using macOS), I changed:

```
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

to:

```
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```